# ASP C# Force download file in database return limited size 32 kb

Tags: c#, asp.net, sybase

I have problem when force download binary file (image/pdf) in database (i'm using Syabase). The code is fine/working, but it return corrupted file if I upload large file ( more than 50 kb- which it will return 32kb size file.
It work fine, if I use file size 10-40 kb, in format pdf or image.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections;
using Sybase.Data.AseClient;
using Sybase.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;
-----------------
conn.Open();
string myquery = "SELECT * FROM pen WHERE p_id=@p_id ";
AseCommand cmd = new AseCommand(myquery, conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@pen_id", AseDbType.VarChar).Value = pen_id;
AseDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (dr.Read())
{
 Response.ClearContent();
 Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"; //hardcore for pdf 
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+dr["file_name"]+"");
 Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr["the_file"]);
 Response.Flush();
 Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess... you probably want to change the structure of your read to a while(dr.Read()) instead of if(dr.Read()).

As-is, you'll only read to the end of the buffer size of the data reader, but you want to keep reading each time your data reader goes through its buffer until you get to the end of the file.  Make sense?

Pull the out all of the Response clearing, ending, and header setup outside of the while loop.

Comment: thanks Ryan, but it still same.
It's look like it can take data from Sybase in 32kb only. I'm still looking for a root cause.